# PostgreSQL Docker container keeps running out of memory

Tags: memory, docker, postgresql

I am developing a software that needs a huge database (62 GB) and decided to use PostgreSQL 9.6. I am running it in a Docker container on a machine running on RedHat. I now need to run a query that uses one COUNT and two GROUP BY on the full data, but every time I run it the server crashes and the `dmesg` command shows that the process was killed due to an `Out of Memory` error.

I limited the memory of the container to 4GB (the host machine has 6 GB RAM) and followed the instructions from this website to configure my database: https://severalnines.com/blog/architecture-and-tuning-memory-postgresql-databases.

I've been trying to resolve this problem for hours now, but I still don't understand what causes it. Please help me :(